# Representation-finite trivial extension algebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Given a quiver algebra A such that its trivial extension T(A) is representation-finite. Is T(A) automatically stable equivalent to a trivial extension algebra of a hereditary representation-finite algebra? I think the answer is yes, but is there also an easy argument?

Comment: I saw a result saying that the trivial extension being representation-finite implies the algebra to be iterated tilted of Dynkin type. This should imply the result. I leave this open for a possibly elementary proof.